# virtualKeycode ToUnicode

Tags: c, windows, unicode, keyboard, keycode

I've been trying to get the unicode character for a given keycode, but i cannot figure out why i have to give so many parameters. From MSDN:

```
int WINAPI ToUnicode(
  _In_      UINT wVirtKey,
  _In_      UINT wScanCode,
  _In_opt_  const BYTE *lpKeyState,
  _Out_     LPWSTR pwszBuff,
  _In_      int cchBuff,
  _In_      UINT wFlags
);
```

I have a VirtualKeycode to use, but why do i need to give it a scancode as well? What is the point of have a virtualKeycode, if you also need a scancode from the keyboard?

What I have tried so far:

```
const unsigned int BUFFER_LENGTH = 3;
WCHAR string[BUFFER_LENGTH];
const BYTE* keyboard = new BYTE[256]; 
unsigned int x = 0x50; //P virtualkeycode
ToUnicode(x,0,keyboard,string,1,0)
```

ToUnicode returns a 0, saying that it cannot convert to Unicode.

Comment: It is mentioned in the MSDN article:  "Typically, ToUnicodeEx performs the translation based on the virtual-key code. In some cases, however, bit 15 of the wScanCode parameter can be used to distinguish between a key press and a key release."

Comment: So what should i pass as wScanCode? It is not optional as the keyboardstate

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski You could try using `MapVirtualKey` to try to obtain the scan code from the virtual key code.

Comment: @jamesdlin that seems pointless to me, i don't need to know if e is pressed to know its e, right?

Comment: I agree it's silly, but I'm just answering your question about what you can pass.

Comment: Why did you pass `1` as the 5th param? It's supposed to be the size in character of the buffer. That should be `BUFFER_LENGTH` in your case.